# Extracting strings of RightToLeft langueges with iTextSharp from a pdf file

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0

I searched for finding a solution of extracting strings of RightToLeft langueges with iTextSharp, but I could not find any way for it. Is it possible extracting strings of RightToLeft langueges from a pdf file with iTextSharp?
With thanks

EDIT:
This Code has very good result:

```
    private void writePdf2()
    {
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        {
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            FontFactory.Register("c:\\windows\\fonts\\tahoma.ttf");
            var tahoma = FontFactory.GetFont("tahoma", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);


            var reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test.pdf");
            int intPageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
            string text = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++)
            {
                text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text.ToString()));
                text = new UnicodeCharacterPlacement
                {
                    Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12)
                }.Apply(text);

                File.WriteAllText("page-" + i + "-text.txt", text.ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: writer.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk("Test. Hello world. Hello people. سلام. کلمه سلام. سلام مردم", tahoma)),
                        //phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(text, tahoma)),
                        x: 300,
                        y: 300,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test2.pdf");
    }
```

But "phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(text, tahoma))" does not have correct output for all strings in the PDF. Therefore I used "PdfStamper" to make a PDF which is suitable for "PdfReader" in "iTextSharp".

Comment: Hhmmm, pdfs internally essentially are lefttoright or toptobottom, so I guess in the end somewhere the order of extracted characters has to be inverted. Most likely a custom text extraction strategy could do the trick. Might be fun to get lines with mixed rtl and ltr content right...

Comment: I used this code but my problem was not solved. `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\salam.pdf");PdfStamper stp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\File1.pdf", FileMode.Create)); stp.Close();reader.Close();`

Comment: Well, that code is the base for *stamping* something onto some PDF file, not for *extracting* something from it.

Comment: Please read Edit part.

Comment: Your code does **not extract text from the PDF** but it **adds text to the PDF**. Or do you mean that you want to extract text from PDFs generated like that? Please clearify! --- *does not have correct output for all strings in the PDF.* - please provide samples for which there is an issue.

Comment: `phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk("Test. Hello world. Hello people. سلام. کلمه سلام. سلام مردم", tahoma))` produces a good result (سلام is سلام) but `phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(text, tahoma))` does not produce a good result (سلام is سالم). I fill "text" in "Phrase" with reading a current PDF file therefore I do not have a good result- in current PDF file I have "سلام" but after reading this PDF file I have "سالم".

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: Post a link to a sample PDF where you have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reproducing the issue

*As initially the OP couldn't provide a sample file, I first tried to reproduce the issue with a file generated by iTextSharp itself.*

My test method first creates a PDF using the `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` with the string constant which according to the OP returns a good result. Then it extracts the text content of that file. Finally it creates a second PDF containing a line created using the good `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` call with the string constant and then several lines created using `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` with the extracted string with or without the post-processing instructions from the OP's code (UTF8-encoding and -decoding; applying `UnicodeCharacterPlacement`) performed.

I could not immediately find the `UnicodeCharacterPlacement` class the OP uses. So I googled a bit and found one such class [here](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1160/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D9%81%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-pdf-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%B7-itextsharp). I hope this is essentially the class used by the OP.

```
public void ExtractTextLikeUser2509093()
{
    string rtlGood = @"C:\Temp\test-results\extract\rtlGood.pdf";
    string rtlGoodExtract = @"C:\Temp\test-results\extract\rtlGood.txt";
    string rtlFinal = @"C:\Temp\test-results\extract\rtlFinal.pdf";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Temp\test-results\extract\");

    FontFactory.Register("c:\\windows\\fonts\\tahoma.ttf");
    Font tahoma = FontFactory.GetFont("tahoma", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

    // A - Create a PDF with a good RTL representation
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(rtlGood, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: pdfWriter.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk("Test. Hello world. Hello people. سلام. کلمه سلام. سلام مردم", tahoma)),
                        x: 500,
                        y: 300,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);
        }
    }

    // B - Extract the text for that good representation and add it to a new PDF
    String textA, textB, textC, textD;
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(rtlGood))
    {
        textA = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
        textB = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textA.ToString()));
        textC = new UnicodeCharacterPlacement
        {
            Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12)
        }.Apply(textA);
        textD = new UnicodeCharacterPlacement
        {
            Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12)
        }.Apply(textB);

        File.WriteAllText(rtlGoodExtract, textA + "\n\n" + textB + "\n\n" + textC + "\n\n" + textD + "\n\n");
    }
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(rtlFinal, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: pdfWriter.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk("Test. Hello world. Hello people. سلام. کلمه سلام. سلام مردم", tahoma)),
                        x: 500,
                        y: 600,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: pdfWriter.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(textA, tahoma)),
                        x: 500,
                        y: 550,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: pdfWriter.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(textB, tahoma)),
                        x: 500,
                        y: 500,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: pdfWriter.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(textC, tahoma)),
                        x: 500,
                        y: 450,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                        canvas: pdfWriter.DirectContent,
                        alignment: Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        phrase: new Phrase(new Chunk(textD, tahoma)),
                        x: 500,
                        y: 400,
                        rotation: 0,
                        runDirection: PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                        arabicOptions: 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The final result:

[image: rtlFinal.pdf]

Thus,

1. I cannot reproduce the issue. Both the final two variants to me look identical in their Arabic contents with the original line. In particular I could not observe the switch from "سلام" to "سالم". Most likely content of the PDF `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test.pdf` (from which the OP extracted the text in his test) is somehow peculiar and so text extracted from it draws with that switch.
2. Applying that `UnicodeCharacterPlacement` class to the extracted text is necessary to get it into the right order.
3. The other post-processing line,

   ```
   text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text.ToString()));
   ```

   does not make any difference and should not be used.

For further analysis we would need that PDF `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test.pdf`.

### Inspecting  salamword.pdf

*Eventually the OP could provide a sample PDF, [salamword.pdf](http://s7.picofile.com/d/5741c9e5-173b-4c90-940e-ea676deb9324/salamword.pdf):*

> I used "PrimoPDF" to create a PDF file with this content: "Test. Hello world. Hello people. سلام. کلمه سلام. سلام مردم".
>
> Next I read this PDF file. Then I received this output: "Test. Hello world. Hello people. م . م . م دم    ".

*Indeed I could reproduce this behavior. So I analyzed the way the Arabic writing was encoded inside...*

***Some background information to start with:***

Fonts in PDFs can have (and in the case at hand do have) a completely custom encoding. In particular embedded subsets often are generated by choosing codes as the characters come, e.g. the first character from a given font used on a page is encoded as `1`, the second different as `2`, the third different as `3` etc.

Thus, simply extracting the codes of the drawn text does not help very much at all (see below for an example from the file at hand). But a font inside a PDF can bring along some extra information allowing an extractor to map the codes to Unicode values. These information might be

- a **ToUnicode** map providing an immediate map code -> Unicode code point;
- an **Encoding** providing a base encoding (e.g. **WinAnsiEncoding**) and differences from it in the form of glyph names; these names may be standard names or names only meaningful in the context of the font at hand;
- **ActualText** entries for a structure element or marked-content sequence.

The PDF specification describes a method using the **ToUnicode** and the **Encoding** information with standard names to extract text from a PDF and presents **ActualText** as an alternative way where applicable. The iTextSharp text extraction code implements the **ToUnicode** / **Encoding** method with standard names.

*Standard names* in this context in the PDF specification are *character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters
in the Symbol font*.

***In the file at hand:***

Let's look at the Arabic text in the line written in Arial. The codes used for the glyphs here are:

> 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 06 07 01 08 02 06 07 01 09 05 0A 0B 01 08 02 06 07

This looks very much like an ad-hoc encoding as described above is used. Thus, using only these information does not help at all.

Thus, let's look at the **ToUnicode** mapping of the embedded Arial subset:

```
<01><01><0020>
<02><02><0645>
<03><03><062f>
<04><04><0631>
<08><08><002e>
<0c><0c><0028>
<0d><0d><0077>
<0e><0e><0069>
<0f><0f><0074>
<10><10><0068>
<11><11><0041>
<12><12><0072>
<13><13><0061>
<14><14><006c>
<15><15><0066>
<16><16><006f>
<17><17><006e>
<18><18><0029>
```

This maps `01` to `0020`, `02` to `0645`, `03` to `062f`, `04` to `0631`, `08` to `002e`, etc. It does not map `05`, `06`, `07`, etc to anything, though.

So the **ToUnicode** map only helps for some codes.

Now let's look at the associated encoding

```
29 0 obj
<</Type/Encoding
  /BaseEncoding/WinAnsiEncoding
  /Differences[ 1
    /space/uni0645/uni062F/uni0631
    /uni0645.init/uni06440627.fina/uni0633.init/period
    /uni0647.fina/uni0644.medi/uni06A9.init/parenleft
    /w/i/t/h
    /A/r/a/l
    /f/o/n/parenright ]
>>
endobj
```

The encoding is based on **WinAnsiEncoding** but all codes of interest are remapped in the **Differences**. There we find numerous standard glyph names (i.e. *character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters
in the Symbol font*) like **space**, **period**, **w**, **i**, **t**, etc.; but we also find several non-standard names like **uni0645**, **uni06440627.fina** etc.

There appears to be a scheme used for these names, **uni0645** represents the character at Unicode code point 0645, and **uni06440627.fina** most likely represents the characters at Unicode code point 0644 and 0627 in some order in some *final* form. But still these names are non-standard for the purpose of text extraction according to the method presented by the PDF specification.

Furthermore, there are no **ActualText** entries in the file at all.

So the reason why only " م . م . م دم   " is extracted is that only for these glyphs there are proper information for the standard PDF text extraction method in the PDF.

By the way, if you copy&paste from your file in Adobe Reader you'll get a similar result, and Adobe Reader has a fairly good implementation of the standard text extraction method.

**TL;DR**

The sample file simply does not contains the information required for text extraction with the method described by the PDF specification which is the method implemented by iTextSharp.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much _mkl_. My problem is for reading current PDF Files. I used "PrimoPDF" to create a PDF file with this content: "Test. Hello world. Hello people. سلام. کلمه سلام. سلام مردم". Next I read this PDF file. Then I received this output: "Test. Hello world. Hello people. م  .     م  . م   دم ".

Comment: When I use  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); Document doc = word.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\salam.docx");
doc.Activate(); doc.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\salam.pdf", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF); doc.Close();` and then use that code, I received "سالم".

Comment: Please share the pdfs involved for reproducing the issue and analysis.

Comment: I made these two images from input, my code and output.
[image 1](http://i68.tinypic.com/1c8lw.png) and [image 2](http://i63.tinypic.com/350wawi.png)

Comment: I made these two images from input, my code and output.
[image 1]( http://i66.tinypic.com/2cgzk7l.png) and [image 2]( http://i65.tinypic.com/6j2ib5.png)

Comment: Please share the pdfs, not images. I cannot reproduce or analyse the issue with images. Furthermore your links all merely show me the tinypic site, not a particular image.

Comment: Sorry. I tried several times, but I could not upload PDFs. But 4 images are visible in their addresses.

Comment: For reproducing and further analysis, the pdfs are necessary, not images. Usually pdfs for stackoverflow questions are shared via a public share in Dropbox or GoogleDrive.

Comment: This link is good? [salamword.pdf](http://s7.picofile.com/d/5741c9e5-173b-4c90-940e-ea676deb9324/salamword.pdf)

Comment: It gets blocked as unsecure download on Windows 10.

Comment: @user2509093 Ok, I could download it on a Windows 7 machine. I'll look into it later.

Comment: @user2509093 Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hello. Thank you _mkl_. Then extracting Persian and Arabic language with iTextSharp is impossible?

Comment: *Then extracting Persian and Arabic language with iTextSharp is impossible?* - As I demonstrated in the first part of my answer, it is possible, the pdf merely must be created by a software which also adds the information necessary for text extraction. And this is not only true for *Persian and Arabic* but even for plain English. Usually a good test is trying to copy&paste from Adobe Reader; text the Reader cannot extract usually is difficult or impossible to extract without OCR.

Comment: If you think an answer has appropriately answered your question, please accept the answer (click the tick at the upper left of the answer).